# How to make a bot that changes channel names in python?

Tags: python, embed, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot using discord.py that when used that command t!control the bot replys with a embeded list of instructions. I want the bot to make it so the next reply that comes from the user that accessed the command will change the channel that they are in to the name they replied with if you get what I am saying.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you have any code that you've tried?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I haven't tried any code yet since im new when it comes to coding for discord but I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this